# Accessing data in mysql database using c# for windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

How to access data from Mysql database in windows 8 app using C#?

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows 8 app, we can specify for example a connection string to read out data stored in a server-side database. Not only would this be a huge security risk (imagine your connection string being on the thousands of devices where your app is downloaded!), it would also be pretty useless to have it there. WinRT has no knowledge of talking with a (remote) database. This means no ADO.NET or LINQ-To-SQL classes are in the API.

So you can occupy data services like OData

OData has a connector for MySQL named MySQLOData, is a code generator tool that works with the OData Producer library for PHP to create the code to implement OData provider feeds for any MySQL database. The tool is open source (BSD license) and written in 100% cross-platform PHP that can be run on Linux, Windows, or Mac OS environments.

Download: http://odatamysqlphpconnect.codeplex.com/ 
Documentation: http://odatamysqlphpconnect.codeplex.com/ 
Article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/02/09/open-source-odata-tools-for-mysql-and-php-developers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[this link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) here will give you the DLL which you can import into your project. Afterwards it's exactly the same as you would make connections to sql-server.

For example:

```
SqlConnection connection;
//would become now
MySqlConnection connection;
```

Comment: though the OP did not specify, I suspect he's writing a Windows 8 Store app for which this will not work.

Comment: @JimO'Neil than it would be a problem indeed, but from the 'extensive' question he wrote, I can't give a better description than this =P